# Microsoft Graph API - Regional Location of Stored Data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In developing a customized storage application using the Microsoft Graph API to write to a OneDrive Tenant, it does not appear that there are any regional endpoints (i.e. US, IRL, EU, etc). The Microsoft Trust Center (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter) assures that the data will be stored in location sensitive regions. Is there a way to validate where the data is stored (I don't see anything in the JSON that is returned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the `x-ms-ags-diagnostic` headers of the response you can find details on which data center handled your sepsonse:

```http
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {
    "ServerInfo": {
        "DataCenter": "West US",
        "Slice": "SliceB",
        "Ring": "NA",
        "ScaleUnit": "002",
        "Host": "AGSFE_IN_17",
        "ADSiteName": "WST"
    }}
```